# php imagecreatefrompng memory limit

Tags: php, memory-limit, imagecreatefrompng

my memory_limit is set to 90M according to phpinfo() on a 1and1 server but I keep getting errors when using imagecreatefrompng()

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 27000832) (tried to allocate 15936 bytes)
```

2700832 bytes is 25.75MB nowhere near 90 and when I download the image it is only 12 MB

Is there another setting that could be limiting the memory?

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but I had the same issue when trying to create temp. files on the server - it turned out that the host had turned on FastCGI on the server - it doesn't handle memory the same as regular Apache. I would look into that and make sure that's not the case with you as well - turning off FastCGI fixed all my memory issues.

Answer (score 0):

you can set your memory limit at runtime by calling

```
    ini_set('memory_limit','128M');
```

2700832/1024/1024 = 2.575 MB

I guess that imagecreatefrompng needs more memory than the image size.

For comparison I hava an 1.7MB image which needs more than 64MB